# SVG rendering with custom fonts fails on ipad

Tags: google-chrome, svg, fonts

i have written this text using svg and it works on chrome and IE as i checked but i doesn't show anything on IPad's Chome.

```
<svg width="180" height="76" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <title>eQuotes</title>
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'MYFONT';
        src: url('./fonts/berlin.eot');
        src: url('./fonts/berlin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('./fonts/berlin.woff') format('woff'),
            url('./fonts/berlin.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('./fonts/berlin.svg#berlin') format('svg');
    }
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
   <text stroke="#7f0000" transform="matrix(1.73839 0 0 1.55447 -176.823 -232.222)" font-weight="bold" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="MYFONT" font-size="24" id="svg_40" y="192.68606" x="152.0512" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Hello There</text>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

any ideas whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG is invalid XML. You have one too many `</g>` at the end, and you have invalid attribute values (`null`). [Validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org), fix your errors, and try again.

Comment: @tomcat Update your question with the actual SVG

Comment: here is link to the actual svg [link](http://static.ekwinox.com/content/images/eQuotes-light.svg)

Comment: @tomcat [That is still invalid.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ekwinox.com%2Fcontent%2Fimages%2FeQuotes-light.svg&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: If you will please point out what am i doing wrong in link of my previous comment

Comment: @tomcat Click on the link of my comment to see the validation errors.